# Reading a file and saving the same exact file c++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am actually writing a c++ program that reads any kind of file and saves it as a bmp file, but first I need to read the file, and thats were the issue is

```
char fileName[] = "test.jpg";

FILE * inFileForGettingSize;//This is for getting the file size
fopen_s(&inFileForGettingSize, fileName, "r");
fseek(inFileForGettingSize, 0L, SEEK_END);
int fileSize = ftell(inFileForGettingSize);
fclose(inFileForGettingSize);


ifstream inFile;//This is for reading the file
inFile.open(fileName);
if (inFile.fail()) {
    cerr << "Error Opening File" << endl;
}
char * data = new char[fileSize];
inFile.read(data, fileSize);


ofstream outFile;//Writing the file back again
outFile.open("out.jpg");
outFile.write(data, fileSize);
outFile.close();
cin.get();
```

But when I read the file, lets say its a plainttext file it allways outputs some wierd charactes at the end, for example:

```
assdassaasd

sdaasddsa
sdadsa
```

passes to:

```
assdassaasd

sdaasddsa
sdadsaÍÍÍ
```

So when I do this with a jpg, exe, etc. It corrupts it.
I am not trying to COPY a file, I know there are other ways for that, Im just trying to read a complete file byte per byte. Thanks.

EDIT:

I found out that those 'Í' are equal to the number of end lines the file has, but this doesn't help me much

Comment: You can seek/tell using an fstream, so not sure why you even need to use C I/O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [newline handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages).

You open the files in text mode (because you use `"r"` instead of `"rb"` for `fopen` and because you don't pass `ios::binary` to your `fstream` `open` calls), and on Windows, text mode translates `"\r\n"` pairs to `"\n"` on reading and back to `"\r\n"` when writing.  The result is that the in-memory size is going to be shorter than the on-disk size, so when you try to write using the on-disk size, you go past the end of your array and write whatever random stuff happens to reside in memory.

You need to open files in binary mode when working with binary data:

```
fopen_s(&inFileForGettingSize, fileName, "rb");

inFile.open(fileName, ios::binary);

outFile.open("out.jpg", ios::binary);
```

For future reference, your copy routine could be improved.  Mixing `FILE*` I/O with `iostream` I/O feels awkward, and opening and closing the file twice is extra work, and (most importantly), if your routine is ever run on a large enough file, it will exhaust memory trying to load the entire file into RAM.  Copying a block at a time would be better:

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 65536;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

while (source.good()) {
  source.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
  dest.write(buffer, source.gcount());
}
```

Comment: Oh... thanks! I was researching that, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary file, so you need to read and write the file as binary; otherwise it's treated as text, and assumed to have newlines that need translation.

In your call to fopen(), you need add the "b" designator:

```
fopen_s(&inFileForGettingSize, fileName, "rb");
```

And in your fstream::open calls, you need to add std::fstream::binary:

```
inFile.open(fileName, std::fstream::binary);
// ...
outFile.open("out.jpg", std::fstream::binary);
```

Comment: Or "ios::binary" instead of "std::fstream::binary"; they both reference the same constant.